# Nginx proxy_pass, define a non-match case?

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I've got 2 files with **proxy_pass** :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain1.fr;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

and

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain2.fr;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2369;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

They both work fine.

Now, **if I go to this server through another domain name** (*defined on my DNS server targeting the same IP address*), eg. www.domain3.fr, instead of a 404, I've got the same result as www.domain2.fr !

I guess it's because of the last `location /`, but how can I do a 404 error if the domain name is not the same than `server_name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered this question so many times I'm thinking of finding a way to make it generic so I could share it when there's a question is asked.

Here's the other answers if you would like to look at it

- [Nginx Subdomain accessible on subdomain its not configured for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21244222/2149092)
- [nginx subdomain ssl redirect redirects top level domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20767735/2149092)
- [nginx reverse proxy redirecting to wrong domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21080263/2149092)

you can read on any one why this is happening, on this reference link [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Simple answer is a small server block to prevent it

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  # return a code maybe or do any thing
  return 404;
}
```

of course reload nginx after that to reflect the settings.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a very common case. Thank you for links and snippet !

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to add a new config :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    access_log off;
    return 404;
}
```

To be a "catch all".
Source : [NGINX multiple server blocks with reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902727/nginx-multiple-server-blocks-with-reverse-proxy)